# can i the use the same Is mouse over event for different text blocks?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, xaml

I have stack panel containing three textblocks bounded with different member variable.I

want to set a property on textblocks foreground based on Is mouse over property. can i use

the same is mouse over property for all textblocks of the panel or i have to set for each

and every textblock? This is the first time i'm using triggers.

Here is my code

```
 <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-3,0,2.932">
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Location}" Foreground="#FFFFF1A5" Style="{StaticResource Textstyle}" />
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="#FFFFF1A5" Style="{StaticResource Textstyle}" />
         <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Age}"Foreground="#FFFFF1A5" Style="{StaticResource Textstyle}" />
                  <StackPanel.Resources>
                     <Style x:Key="Textstyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                          <Style.Triggers>
                             <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>                                                                                                       
                             </Trigger>
                           </Style.Triggers>
                     </Style>                                               
                  </StackPanel.Resources>
  </StackPanel>
```

Is there anything wrong in my approach?

Because im not getting any result from this.Please answer my question.please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local Foreground property is overriding the Style. Set the default Foreground property in the style instead.

```
<StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,-3,0,2.932">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="Textstyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFF1A5"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Location}" Style="{StaticResource Textstyle}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Style="{StaticResource Textstyle}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Age}" Style="{StaticResource Textstyle}" />
</StackPanel>
```